# How to store objectID property in Typescript Interface?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, interface

i'm implementing interface and mongoose schemas in Typescript.
The struggle with the follow issue:

The Schema should have contain these properties:

```
let MovementSchema = new Schema
    ({
        movementName : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MovementName'},
        rounds: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Round'}]
    });
```

the Interface look like this:

```
import { ObjectId } from "bson";

export interface IMovement {
    movementType : ObjectId,
    rounds : [ ObjectId ]
}
```

and the question is, the `ObjectId` is the good type to create properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `ObjectId` it should be stored as a `string`.